# Replace DOMDocument Parent node with child node PHP

Tags: php, domdocument

This is my HTML code and I wanna replace `<a>` tag with `<img>` tag using `DOMDocument`.

```
<a href='xxx.com'><img src='yyy.jpg'></a>
```

Here is the `PHP` code:

```
$newNode=cj_DOMinnerHTML($link); //$link refer to anchor tag 
$image_dom = new DOMDocument();
$image_dom->loadHTML($newNode);
$link->parentNode->replaceChild($image_dom, $link); //this replace making my parent node empty
```

`cj_DOMinnerHTML` is function which return child nodes as HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello_ mate.

If I understood you well you want to remove the `<a>` tags and I don't know what exactly your function `cj_DOMinnerHTML` is doing, but I see that your are passing instance of `DOMDocument` to `replaceChild` method as first argument which is wrong. Refer to [**documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php) to see how exactly is `replaceChild` working (it accepts two arguments of type `DOMNode`). Anyway I give you a code snippet that is replacing the `<a>` tags. Please read the comments that I put in code and try to change the code for your use case.

```
$html = '
<div id="container">
    <a href="xxx.com"><img src="yyy.jpg"></a>
    <a href="aaa.com"><img src="aaa.jpg"></a>
    <a href="bbb.com"><img src="bbb.jpg"></a>
    <a href="ccc.com"><img src="ccc.jpg"></a>
    <a href="ddd.com"><img src="ddd.jpg"></a>
    <a href="eee.com"><img src="eee.jpg"></a>
</div>';

// load the dom document
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
if (!$dom->loadHTML($html)) {
    echo '<h2>Error handle this ...</h2>';
}

// instantiate DOMXPath object
$finder = new \DOMXPath($dom);

// get all <a> tags of element that has id="container"
$anchors = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@id), ' '), 'container')]/descendant::a");

// loop through all <a>
foreach ($anchors as $a) {
    $parent = $a->parentNode;
    // the following row of code will actually remove the <a> tag
    $parent->replaceChild($a->childNodes->item(0), $a);
}

// show output
echo htmlspecialchars($dom->saveHTML());
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="container"> 
            <img src="yyy.jpg"> 
            <img src="aaa.jpg"> 
            <img src="bbb.jpg"> 
            <img src="ccc.jpg"> 
            <img src="ddd.jpg"> 
            <img src="eee.jpg"> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope you will understand the code and you will be able to modify it to work for your needs.

Good luck friend!

Comment: thank you. 
                      $link->parentNode->insertBefore($img, $link);
                       $link->parentNode->removeChild($link); i solved my issue by this code. i'll try with your code.

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad that this was helpful for you :)